# filter table column and view the data in the another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

table 'acad_concerns'

```
id  student_name    start_date  end_date    concern         comments

 1  Anne Curtis     2013-02-27  2013-02-28  Academics       this acad.. 
2   benedict grey   2013-02-27  2013-02-28  Academics       also acad..
3   Anne Curtis     2013-02-27  2013-02-28  Accomodation    this is aco
4   benedict grey   2013-02-27  2013-02-28  Accomodation    also accomo
```

i want to view like this:

```
    student_name    Accademics   Accomodation   


    Anne Curtis     this acad..  this is accom..
    benedict grey   also acad..  also accom..
```

Comment: share your code so we can help better .

Comment: ***what did you try***?

Comment: At least *try* to explain in a coherent way using English sentences what you want to do and what problem you have. Often this leads to discovering the solution automatically.

Comment: What a good question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **I can't explain this**

Let me explain it for you.

You are looking for *pivoting* the `comments` values for the `concern` for each student. Unfortunately, MySQL has no pivot table operator.

However, you can use the `CASE` expression to do this. Like so:

```
SELECT 
  student_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN concern = 'Academics'   THEN comments END) AS 'Accademics',
  MAX(CASE WHEN concern = 'Accomodation' THEN comments END) AS 'Accomodation'
FROM acad_concern    
GROUP BY student_name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d022/2)

This will give you:

```
|  STUDENT_NAME |  ACCADEMICS | ACCOMODATION |
----------------------------------------------
|   Anne Curtis | this acad.. |  this is aco |
| benedict grey | also acad.. |  also accomo |
```

For multiple `concern`s and you don't need to write them manually, you have to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(concern = ''',
      concern, ''', comments, NULL)) AS ', '''', concern , '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM acad_concern;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT student_name, ', @sql , '
    FROM acad_concern    
    GROUP BY student_name;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d022/6)

Comment: is there another answer fro this ?

Comment: @user1528552 - Sorry, this is the answer I know for this. It might be other answer, but I don't know other way for doing this.

Comment: what if the accomodation is empty?

Comment: only the academics has the data

Comment: thaks for the answer...

Comment: @user1528552 Can you please show me that query that gave you the `accomodation` empty, please check the splinning of `accomodation`. Also try to edit the demo example show this issue, this will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT distinct student_name
        (SELECT comments FROM acad_concern where student_name=student.student_name where concern='Accademics') 
    as Accademics,
        (SELECT comments FROM acad_concern where student_name=student.student_name where concern='Accomodation')
     as Accomodation  
        FROM acad_concern student
```